# shinyapps.io: Error in .jcheck: Java Exception <no description because toString() failed

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, rjava, rjdbc

I have a shiny app that works fine in my laptop. However, when I deploy it to shinyapp.io, I get the error message in the title above. It uses RJDBC to connect to a database to get data. I am confused why it works locally but not in shinyapps.io. Below is the session info for my local R installation. Further, rJava::.jinit() returns 0.

```
> sessionInfo() R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) Platform:
> x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build
> 19045)
> 
> Matrix products: default
> 
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  [2]
> LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United
> States.utf8 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           [5]
> LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    
> 
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
> datasets  methods   [7] base     
> 
> other attached packages:  [1] rsconnect_0.8.29 DT_0.26         
> plotly_4.10.1     [4] ggplot2_3.4.0    gridExtra_2.3    RJDBC_0.2-10  
> [7] rJava_1.0-6      DBI_1.1.3        openxlsx_4.2.5.1 [10]
> purrr_1.0.0      lubridate_1.9.0  timechange_0.1.1 [13] tidyr_1.2.1   
> dplyr_1.0.10     shiny_1.7.4     
> 
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_1.0.9       
> assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.31      [4] packrat_0.9.0     utf8_1.2.2 
> mime_0.12          [7] R6_2.5.1          httr_1.4.4       
> pillar_1.8.1      [10] rlang_1.0.6       lazyeval_0.2.2    curl_4.3.3 
> [13] fontawesome_0.4.0 rstudioapi_0.14   data.table_1.14.6 [16]
> jquerylib_0.1.4   htmlwidgets_1.6.0 munsell_0.5.0     [19]
> compiler_4.2.2    httpuv_1.6.7      pkgconfig_2.0.3   [22] askpass_1.1
> htmltools_0.5.4   openssl_2.0.5     [25] tidyselect_1.2.0 
> tibble_3.1.8      fansi_1.0.3       [28] viridisLite_0.4.1 withr_2.5.0
> later_1.3.0       [31] grid_4.2.2        jsonlite_1.8.4   
> xtable_1.8-4      [34] gtable_0.3.1      lifecycle_1.0.3  
> magrittr_2.0.3    [37] scales_1.2.1      zip_2.2.2         cli_3.5.0  
> [40] stringi_1.7.8     cachem_1.0.6      promises_1.2.0.1  [43]
> bslib_0.4.2       ellipsis_0.3.2    generics_0.1.3    [46] vctrs_0.5.1
> tools_4.2.2       glue_1.6.2        [49] crosstalk_1.2.0  
> fastmap_1.1.0     yaml_2.3.6        [52] colorspace_2.0-3 
> memoise_2.0.1     sass_0.4.4
```

Comment: I have also had this issue for about a year now. Running on Debian 11. Similar R session info to the above. I have determined that the error does not occur when running with openjdk 8 and lower. But this is hardly comforting because that package is ancient.

Comment: @bk18, so do you recommend me to use openjdk 8?

Comment: I mean you could, and on my machine that fixes things. But this is not really a solution, as openjdk8 is a very old package and will likely be leaving the standard package repos soon enough.

Comment: You are right. I switched to Python with reticulate. It is slower though until it created the anaconda virtual environment